# text box should be validated to accept a particular value on selecting value from dropdownlist in web form using ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have one dropdown list which contains 3 values: breakfast,lunch,dinner.
and two text box which should only accept the time.

Condition 1: if selected value is breakfast , user can only enter time between 7 am to 10am in text box.
Condition 2: if selected value is lunch, user can only enter time between 12:00 pm to 2:00 pm
Condition 3: if selected value is dinner , user can only enter time between 8:00pm to 10:00 pm

Comment: What is your question exaclty?

Comment: post your code and describe it clearly

Comment: use custom validators https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5db6z8k.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't include any existing code, I will not explain my work. :)

.aspx

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMeal" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlMeal_SelectedIndexChanged" required>
        <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="Select from the list..." />
        <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Breakfast" />
        <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="Lunch" />
        <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="Dinner" />
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtStart" runat="server" type="time" required />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEnd" runat="server" type="time" required /><br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
</form>
```

.aspx.cs

```
protected void ddlMeal_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ddlMeal.SelectedValue != "") // if meal type is selected
    {
        if (ddlMeal.SelectedValue == "1") // Breakfast
        {
            txtStart.Attributes.Add("min", "07:00:00");
            txtStart.Attributes.Add("max", "10:00:00");
            txtEnd.Attributes.Add("min", "7:00:00");
            txtEnd.Attributes.Add("max", "10:00:00");
        }
        else if (ddlMeal.SelectedValue == "2") // Lunch
        {
            txtStart.Attributes.Add("min", "12:00:00");
            txtStart.Attributes.Add("max", "14:00:00");
            txtEnd.Attributes.Add("min", "12:00:00");
            txtEnd.Attributes.Add("max", "14:00:00");
        }
        else // Dinner
        {
            txtStart.Attributes.Add("min", "20:00:00");
            txtStart.Attributes.Add("max", "22:00:00");
            txtEnd.Attributes.Add("min", "20:00:00");
            txtEnd.Attributes.Add("max", "22:00:00");
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** I only tested the attribute value 'time' using Google Chrome.

Cheers!